# Problems tagging equations in \[ \] environment

Tags: math-mode, errors

I'm not sure about the common practices in presenting code here, so I'm sure I'll do something wrong, I thank you for your patience.

I'm using overleaf.com.

Now, the following code will compile correctly:

```
By exercise 5.4, the line $L_P$ is given by
\[
L_P=C_X(P)(X)+C_Y(P)Y+C_Z(P)Z.
\]
```

But i want to tag this equation (and hopefully with something other than a number as it seems silly to call it Equation 1 if it's the only equation.  Using `\begin{equation}\end{equation}` is working but I don't know if I can change the `(1)` for an `(*)`).

If I try

```
By exercise 5.4, the line $L_P$ is given by
\[
L_P=C_X(P)(X)+C_Y(P)Y+C_Z(P)Z.\tag{\ast}
\]
```

then I get a correctly compiled pdf as far as I can see, with my expected result, but I get the following list of errors (marked on the "\]" line precisely):

```
Missing $ inserted.

Extra }, or forgotten $.

Missing } insterted.

Display math should end with $$.
```

What is going on?

EDIT:

Just checked and

```
\begin{equation}
L_P=C_X(P)(X)+C_Y(P)Y+C_Z(P)Z.\tag{\ast}
\end{equation}
```

gives me the exact same problem. But all works fine if I remove the `\tag{\ast}`.

Comment: Use `\tag{$\ast$}`

Comment: Can you provide something more comprehensive that we can check against? Something like a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Comment: By design, `\[...\]` is an unnumbered display.  `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` is a one-line *numbered* display.  Inserting a `\tag` in a numbered display will substitute that value for the default number.

Comment: @Sigur That does it. Excellent! Thanks everybody.

Comment: @Sigur an answer...? :)

Comment: the error as equation labels/numbers are traditionally set in text mode and `\ast` is a math mode command